# How to determine number of new unique values being added to existing group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm not even sure how best to phrase this question, which may be why I'm having so much difficulty finding an answer.  Here's an example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  user = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  period = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3),
  product = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "c", "d", "a", "b", "b", "a")
)
```

```
  user period product
1     1      1       a
2     1      2       b
3     1      3       b
4     1      3       c
5     2      1       a
6     2      2       a
7     2      3       c
8     2      3       d
9     3      1       a
10    3      2       b
11    3      3       b
12    3      3       a
```

First question: I have a group of users three users, who are receiving products over three different time periods.  I want to know, for the latest time period (the third one), how many users received new products that they haven't received before.

Notably in some of the time periods, users may receive more than one product.  In this example, the only time they've received more than one product is in the third period.

The answer to this first question should be that two users have received something new (user 1 and 2)

Second question: How would you then get a count of the number of new products being received by users?

The answer should be, user 1 received 1 new product, user two received 2 new products, user three received 0 new products.

Comment: Please show the precise output expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dummy variables for each product so that you can calculate the statistics faster, at least in the following steps.

You can order the data table based on the periods and divide it depending on the period you specify (in your case-- period 3).

Then check for the users to see whether they receive a new product that they have not received before, with `colSums` function.

Finally, make a quick `for` loop for each user.

The result table will show who the users are (`user`), whether they received a new product (`is_new_product`), if so, how many new products they received (`how_many`), and what kind of new product they received (`what`).

If you sum the column of `is_new_product`, you will receive the answer to Questions 1, which is 2.

If you look at the column `how_many`, you will receive an answer to Question 2, which is User 1 received 1 new product, and User 2 received 2 new products.

Additionally, you can see the product information in the `what` column.

```
library(fastDummies)

df <- data.frame(
  user = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  period = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3),
  product = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "c", "d", "a", "b", "b", "a")
)



### Make a dummy variable to make calculations easier
df$product <- as.factor(df$product)
df <- fastDummies::dummy_cols(df, select_columns = c("product"),remove_selected_columns = T)


## Order the data based on periods
df <- df[order(df$period,decreasing = F),]
```

```
## For loop create some empty vectors
user <- c()
is_new_product <- c()
how_many <- c()
what <- c()

for (n_user in 1:3) {
  
  user[n_user] <- n_user
  
  res <-
    colSums(df[df$period != 3 &
                 df$user == n_user, 3:ncol(df)]) - colSums(df[df$period == 3 &
                                                           df$user == n_user, 3:ncol(df)])
  
  is_new_product[n_user] <- as.numeric(any(res<0))
  how_many[n_user] <- sum(res==-1)
  what[n_user] <- paste0(names(which(res==-1)),collapse = " | ")
  
  
}


result <- data.frame(user,is_new_product,how_many,what)
result
```

Results

```
> result
  user is_new_product how_many                  what
1    1              1        1             product_c
2    2              1        2 product_c | product_d
3    3              0        0
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want

```
first <-  df %>%  group_by(user, product) %>% slice_min(period) %>% rename(first=period)
last <-  df %>%  group_by(user, product) %>% slice_max(period) %>% rename(last=period)

df <- full_join(first, last) %>% mutate(new_product = if_else(first ==3 & last==3,1,0 ) ) %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% summarise(new_products = sum(new_product))
```

Edit: Adjusting the last bit to give you an extra column with products received for first time in period 3.

```
df <- full_join(first, last) %>% 
  mutate(new_product = if_else(first ==3 & last==3,1,0 ) ) %>%
  mutate(product = if_else(new_product==1,product,"" )) %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  summarise(new_products = sum(new_product), products = paste(product, collapse = ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R approach using an array:

```
tbl <- xtabs(~product+period+user, df)
results <- apply(tbl, 3, function(x) rowSums(x) == x[, 3] & x[, 3] > 0)
cat("Number of Products First Received in Period 3 by User (Column)\n") ; colSums(results)
# Number of Products First Received in Period 3 by User (Column)
# 1 2 3 
# 1 2 0 
cat("Number of Products First Received in Period 3 by Product (Column)\n") ; rowSums(results)
# Number of Products First Received in Period 3 by Product (Column)
# a b c d 
# 0 0 2 1
```